# Finding field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c},\sqrt{d})$ containing $1 + 2^{1/3}$

Tags: field-theory

Can we find $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$ such that $1+2^{1/3}$ is in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c},\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: What have you tried? This is a fairly routine exercise in degrees of field extensions.

Comment: I found the minimal polynomial of 1+2^1/3, It is of degree 3 over Q

Comment: So if the minimum polynomial is degree $3$ what does that tell you about the degree of extension containing $1+2^{1/3}$?

Comment: Can $3$ divide a power of $2$?

Answer (score 2):

No. Think about the degrees of the extensions.